# GLTF Animation doesn't play when adding in material Three.js

Tags: three.js, gltf

I have a working GLTF animation that automatically starts playing when the page loads, however whenever I try to add a material to it, the animation no longer plays but the material appears. How do I fix this or if there is an easier way just to add a block colour to a gltf model please let me know, thanks.

```js
    var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    loader.setDRACOLoader( new THREE.DRACOLoader() );
    // Load a glTF resource
    loader.load(
      // resource URL
      '../models/fox3.gltf',
      // called when the resource is loaded
      function ( gltf ) {

        gltf.animations; // Array<THREE.AnimationClip>
        gltf.scene; // THREE.Scene
        gltf.scenes; // Array<THREE.Scene>
        gltf.cameras; // Array<THREE.Camera>
        gltf.asset; // Object

        //Loading in and positioning model
        var object = gltf.scene;
        object.scale.set(10,10,10);
        object.position.set (-300, 20,-400);
        object.rotation.y = 0.5;
 
        //Playing Animation
         mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(gltf.scene);
         console.log(gltf.animations)
         mixer.clipAction( gltf.animations[0] ).play();


        //Adding texture/colour to model (causes animation to stop playing)
         // materialObj = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: "#9E4300"} );
         // object.traverse(function(child){
         //   if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh){
         //     //child.material = materialObj;
         //   }
         // });


        console.log(object);
        scene.add( object )
      });
```

Comment: try `materialObj = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: "#9E4300", skinning: true} );`

Comment: thank you I love you you saved my uni project <3

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

> or if there is an easier way just to add a block colour to a gltf model please let me know, thanks.

I'll address this last part of your question.  The `MeshBasicMaterial` has the lighting calculations turned off, and in glTF this is supported with an extension called [`KHR_materials_unlit`](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/tree/master/extensions/2.0/Khronos/KHR_materials_unlit).

Here's a sample model called [BoxUnlit.gltf](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/ba4d8404d9e8450851ae3932c12a557cfa94e2ba/Specs/Data/Models/PBR/BoxUnlit/BoxUnlit.gltf) that shows this extension in action.  Two key places to note are [ExtensionsUsed](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/ba4d8404d9e8450851ae3932c12a557cfa94e2ba/Specs/Data/Models/PBR/BoxUnlit/BoxUnlit.gltf#L7) at the top, and the [material](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/ba4d8404d9e8450851ae3932c12a557cfa94e2ba/Specs/Data/Models/PBR/BoxUnlit/BoxUnlit.gltf#L115-L127) near the bottom.

One major gotcha here is that the material's `BaseColorFactor` is specified in linear colorspace, while textures are provided in sRGB colorspace.  So you have to take your chosen color and convert it to linear, [typically](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/blob/13fbbd2e9991a9ae56c6538699c2265665b7ef24/Source/Scene/processPbrMaterials.js#L471) by mathematically raising each component to the power of 2.2.

For example, your question contains color value `#9E4300`, which in `0..255` scale is equal to `(158, 67, 0)`.  Divide each number by 255, then raise by 2.2:

```
  Red == (158 / 255.0) ** 2.2 == 0.348864834
Green == ( 67 / 255.0) ** 2.2 == 0.052841625
 Blue == (  0 / 255.0) ** 2.2 == 0.0
```

Use those values as the RGB values of the glTF model's `BaseColorFactor`, along with an alpha value of 1.0, like so:

```
"materials": [
    {
        "pbrMetallicRoughness": {
            "baseColorFactor": [
                0.348864834,
                0.052841625,
                0.0,
                1.0
            ]
        },
        "extensions": {
            "KHR_materials_unlit": {}
        }
    }
],
```

With that, ThreeJS should [automatically select](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/4510e9311f7477547e82cbed7894772635e88a84/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js#L383-L393) the MeshBasicMaterial for the model.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the skinning to true on the material of gltb and it should work. I had the same problem earlier.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right, sorry for late reply.